# Android - Progress bar practice

Tags: android

Well, I have 1 activity that allow the user to upload picture (it depends on the user to upload pictures or not). I want to show this progress bar only when the user upload a picture:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/wiColorQuiteBlack"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/linear_progressBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_drive_file_white_24dp"/>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/wi_progress_uploading"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:progressTint="@color/white"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

What I do: The progress bar is "gone" and when the user start to upload a picture this change to "visible".. My question is: It is a good practice? Or should I create the linearlayout + imageview + progressbar programatically?

Comment: what are you using uploading script try to use async it provide you functions for same

Comment: Do whichever way you like or you can even use a ProgressDialog

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to use ProgressDialog because doesn't fit with my design. I uploaded a picture of my progressbar

Comment: Yes ofc I'm using async task, I just don't know if is good practice have the view in "gone" then change to visible

Comment: @DexSebas the alternative is worse IMO, creating UI runtime is not cool

Comment: Well, thanks for your answers guys. I will let the progress gone in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a subjective question, but I would try to keep as much of the view in XML as possible, which is why I personally would recommend having it set to `View.GONE`, then setting it to visible when it is needed.

This way, you won't have too much cross-over with the view logic in both Java and XML.

Writing views in Java just plain sucks too :(